# Python Import Class via Locate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using AWS C9 to write my python script if that has any bearing on my following question.

I am new to python and am trying to import a class via a variable name. I found this code

`my_controller = 'MyController'
my_class = locate('path.to.'+my_controller)`

and it seems to work but when I go to call

`my_class.method()`

I get

`AttributeError: module 'path.to.MyController' has no attribute 'method'`

I can't quit seem to figure out how to import my class in python when the py file is a variable. I wish I could do something like this

`from path.to import my_controller as controller`

but then I get an error like this

`cannot import name 'my_controller': ImportError`

EDIT: It looks like my python version is python3.6

EDIT: my MyController.py file looks like this

```
class MyController():
    print('FILE: MyController')

    def method(self, event, context):
        print('MyController.method')
```

Comment: Well, it seems like the module is called `MyController`; `my_controller` is just the arbitrary variable name you used. Does `from path.to import MyController as controller` work?

Comment: Also, is `MyController` supposed to be a class or a module? You seem to assume it's a class, judging from your variable names, but the error says its a module. Probably you first have to create an instance of some class from that module before you can use the method.

Comment: yes MyController is a class `class MyController():` give me a second and i'll ask your first question

Comment: yes if i do `from path.to import MyController as controller` it works just fine ... when I try to use the variable `my_controller` is when it messes up

Comment: is it because `my_controller` is a string? or does that matter? I found other solutions on stackover flow that use `locate` and `__import__` that seem to work but then I can never call the methods under my class

Comment: It's because there is no variable `my_controller` in that module's namespace. Why do you think there should be?

Comment: because `my_controller = 'MyController'` ... im new to python trying to take over a project on the fly ... looks like I found a solution below however. Now I just need to figure out how to call a method from the class when the method is a variable

Comment: Can't you just do `import path.to.MyController` and then `instance = MyController.MyController()`? Here, the first `MyController` is the module, and the second is the class with the same name _inside_ the module.

Comment: Yes, to dynamically import a name with a string you should use `importlib`

Comment: Use `gettatr` to get an attribute from an object using a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like I finally found a solution that works

`module = importlib.import_module('path.to.MyController')
my_class = getattr(module, 'MyController')
my_instance = my_class()
my_instance.method(event, context)`